# Regex to redirect a url using url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

OK, I'm wondering if someone can lend a hand with a regex I'm trying to write.

Basically, what I want to do is use IIS urlrewrite module to do a redirect to a specific URL if the user accesses a URL on another site.  The only catch is I have to also capture a bit of the query string, and move it into the redirect.
so here is the input, the URL that a user may access would look like:

**https://of.example.com/sfsv3.aspx?waform=pro&language=en**

I want to match that URL (either http or https, case insensitive), and capture from it also one piece of information, the two letter language code.  then the url i want to forward the user to looks like:

**http://example.com/ca/en/ppf**

(where en is replaced by whatever i captured above)

So, I'm working with IIS Rewrite module, and I've gotten my input data and regex in, so far the regex pattern I have is this:

```
https?://of.example.com/sfsv3.aspx\?waform=pro&amp;(language=(..))
```

so basically i'm matching the whole string, plus a group and a subgroup for language and it's code.  in the IIS test pattern dialog, this is working.

I get the following

{R:1} language=en

{R:2} en

great!  so then my IIS rewrite rule should look like this to redirect the user:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
          <match url="https?://of.example.com/sfsv3.aspx\?waform=pro&amp;(language=(..))" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/ca/{R:2}/ppf" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

this all seems right to me.  however, the redirect is not occurring.  it seems to have a problem with the part \? (an escaped question mark to mark the start of the query string).  if this is included, then the redirect simply does not happen.

Can you help me figure out how to get it work?

Comment: Do you just need to escape the backslash? i.e., `.aspx\\?waform`

Comment: no, the backslash is not literal.  it's there only to escape the ? that is right after it.

Comment: Why not `https?://of.example.com/sfsv3.aspx\?waform=pro&(language=(..))`?

Comment: if you don't replace & with &amp; then the web.config file is not valid and the site cannot be used.  see earlier, similiar question where I got that answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390162/regex-to-extract-a-part-out-of-a-url-and-use-it-as-a-reference-in-url-rewrite/31392786

after figuring out I needed to htmlencode the entity i was expecting it to work, but still, currently no redirect occurs

Comment: I hope I'm not beating a dead horse here, so my apologies if I am... I know your backslash isn't literal, but neither is the `match` regex (I assume) which would mean you need to escape that backslash. In other words, `"\\?"` and `@"\?"` are equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to escape my backslash, as it is already an escape character.  In any case, i've tried both:
sfsv3.aspx\?waform=pro&amp;(language=(..))
sfsv3.aspx\\?waform=pro&amp;(language=(..))

and neither will trigger the redirect.  The first one works in the regex tester, while the second does not.

this will also work in the regex tester, escaping the & with a backslash instead of making it an htmlentity. (also escaped the . instead of having it match any char)

sfsv3.aspx\.aspx\?waform=pro\&(language=(..))

however, this cannot be compiled or run so I am still stuck

Comment: here it is so you can check it out: http://regexr.com/3bcsr

what's there now is working to find a match.  however, it cannot be built or run because of the & sign.

I get: The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

and: entity is not defined, pointing at the &(l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the record, I figured it out.  this is a special case of regex, running it inside a web.config as part of a urlrewrite action.  in that case, you can't handle the query string with simple regex, you have to put in conditions on the query string.  Here's what eventually ended up working:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
                    <match url="sfsv3.aspx\.aspx" ignoreCase="true"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="subject=PROPRCH" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(..)/subject" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/ca/{C:1}/forms/ppf" appendQueryString="false"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```