# Regular expressions redirection

Tags: c#, regex, redirect

I want to set redirection from 
www.somesite.com/products/dynamicstring/randomtext1/randomtext2
to www.somesite.com/products/dynamicstring

Is it possible to do that through Regex ?

It means if my incming url is 
www.somesite.com/products/myproducts/test1/test2 it should redirect to www.somesite.com/products/myproducts/

just briefing more about this :
@TomLord i am using  HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(matchingDefinition.To)  i have all the redirects "From" and "To" in a class object, in the form of REGEX expressions.Example  in From "/product/*" and To "/products" , i am reading these object and trying to redirect them, but i am not able to redirect something like /products/dynamicstring/randomtext1/  to /products/dynamicstring where dynamic string is random string , i dont find any regular expression which can be use to do this. For example  /products/samples/randomtext1 should redirect to /products/samples/

Comment: Note Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: If you can access the server, you can use a rule to redirect something like [Regex to redirect a url using url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393567/regex-to-redirect-a-url-using-url-rewrite)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you having? What language/platform are you trying to implement this redirection on? (For example, `nginx`???)

Comment: From your example, it looks like you might be interested in a URL Rewrite rather than a HTTP Redirection? Regular Expressions can't actually do much more than represent a string, or part of a string, in a specific way. So, as someone else said - you can use regular expressions to get a new URL, based on an old one, and then redirect to the new URL.

Comment: @PeterAbolins i am using http redirection only

Answer (score 1):

Redirection cannot be done with regex alone. Google a bit what is a regular expression in reality. The short answer is: it's string-like expression that describes search pattern. So it can't redirect, not even replace a substring with substring or do anything else then match and capture parts of the matched string.

That being said, regex can help us do what you wanna. I am gonna assume you can use Javascript, cause I can't put a solution in every language. I am also gonna assume you will try to go over the code not copy paste and press enter. If you only need that hire a programmer. If you use another language, principle should be the same:

- obtain URL
- define regex
- use capture group to extract the part of your URL that you need
- construct a new URL
- redirect to it

While matching the URLs in general is a fair bit more complex, like:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[\w]+\.)(?:\.?[\w]{2,})+$
```

As long as you are sure you will only be getting URLs and in the format you wanna, we will do it far simpler.

Basically, let's say you have:

- some text with 2 dots that ends in com
- then a /products/dynamicstring/
- then text
- then /
- then text

As a regex that is:

```
/\w*.\w*.com\/products\/dynamicstring\/\w*\/\w*/g
```

Curde matching is done, but we still need to add a capture group we will use to extract part of the string we need:

```
/(\w*.\w*.com\/products\/)dynamicstring\/\w*\/\w*/g
```

Oke, now let's leverage this regex to do rest of the work:

Define regex:

```
var regex = /\w*.\w*.com\/products\/dynamicstring\/\w*\/\w*/g;
```

Get current URL. If you already have URL use it.

```
var currUrl = window.location.href;
```

Extract capture group from string:

```
var match = regex.exec(currUrl);
```

Use that to get a new URL from old one:

```
var redirectUrl =  match[1] + myproducts/
```

Finally, we redirect with:

```
window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
```

I wrote all this straight from my head so I recommend you go over each step, look how it works, read some documentation about functions used. You might find an error as well as learn a lot.

Comment: I am willing to bet that your assumption is wrong: "I am also gonna assume you will try to go over the code not copy paste and press enter".

Comment: I can hope. If not him, maybe someone else finds this useful :) I too remember the time when I was noob and regex seemed powerful but scary and I couldn't ask the right question.

Comment: Thanks @DanteTheSmith , i will try to learn and implement it, will not do copy paste for sure :)

Comment: @DanteTheSmith thanks for the detailed walk through,i like to share couple of things : myproducts is not static it can be dynamic, it is basically product family which can be anything, so we cant use this hardcoded in regex, secondlly url can be too long for example /products/productfamily//a/b/c/d should also redirect to product/productfamily

Comment: I am using _regex.IsMatch(pageUrl); so i have regex but it is not handeling my requirement, i would try some more things.

Comment: I couldn't extrapolate that from info provided before. So, we need to change regex to match anything after the desired  www.somesite.com/products/. That is the part that doesn't change?  How do you know what comes after that?  Maybe you need regex only to match some smaller part, like site name? And then have paired values stored as a map somewhere that gives you redirect URL from site name or?